# Slow drag & drop JPEG pictures in JSF page

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, graphicimage

In my JSF application, I want to drag  and drop  JPEG pictures (30 pictures with size ~ 10Mo) and I'm facing in a slow charging page and pictures.
I'm proceeding on compressing these pictures with this code below:

```
    public void reduceImageQuality(int sizeThreshold, UploadedFile file, String destImg) throws Exception {
    float quality = 0.05f;
    long fileSize = file.getSize();
    if (fileSize <= sizeThreshold) {
        System.out.println("Image file size is under threshold");
        return;
    }
    Iterator iter = ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName("jpeg");

    ImageWriter writer = (ImageWriter) iter.next();

    ImageWriteParam iwp = writer.getDefaultWriteParam();

    iwp.setCompressionMode(ImageWriteParam.MODE_EXPLICIT);
    BufferedImage originalImage = ImageIO.read(file.getInputstream());
    IIOImage image = new IIOImage(originalImage, null, null);

    float percent = 0.01f;   // 10% of 1  

    while (fileSize > sizeThreshold) {
        if (percent >= quality) {
            percent = percent * 0.1f;
        }
        quality -= percent;
        File fileOut = new File(destImg);
        if (fileOut.exists()) {
            fileOut.delete();
        }
        try (FileImageOutputStream output = new FileImageOutputStream(fileOut)) {
            writer.setOutput(output);

            iwp.setCompressionQuality(quality);

            writer.write(null, image, iwp);

            File fileOut2 = new File(destImg);
            long newFileSize = fileOut2.length();
            if (newFileSize == fileSize) {
                // cannot reduce more, return  
                break;
            } else {
                fileSize = newFileSize;
            }
            System.out.println("quality = " + quality + ", new file size = " + fileSize);
        }
    }

    writer.dispose();
}
```

And for my XHTML code:

```
    <h:form id="firstGenForm"    enctype="multipart/form-data" >
    <h:panelGrid columns="1" style="margin-left:40px;">  
        <p:outputPanel id="imageForPenetrationPointPublic" styleClass="slot">  
            <h:panelGrid columns="1"  rendered="#{generationTdeEbmMB.selectedImageForPenetrationPointPublic!= null}">
                <p:graphicImage   url="/images/#{generationTdeEbmMB.selectedImageForPenetrationPointPublic}" style="width: 100%;height: 260px;"/> 
            </h:panelGrid>
        </p:outputPanel>

        <p:droppable for="imageForPenetrationPointPublic" tolerance="fit" activeStyleClass="ui-state-highlight" datasource=":availablePictureForm:availablePicturesDGrid" onDrop="handleDrop">
            <p:ajax listener="#{generationTdeEbmMB.onImageForPenetrationPointPublicDrop}" update="imageForPenetrationPointPublic " />
        </p:droppable>
    </h:panelGrid>
</h:form>
<h:form id="availablePictureForm" >
    <p:fieldset legend="Photos disponibles " rendered="#{generationTdeEbmMB.uploadedImageNameList.size() != 0}">  
        <p:scrollPanel style="width:400px;height: 600px;">
            <p:dataGrid id="availablePicturesDGrid" value="#{generationTdeEbmMB.uploadedImageNameList}" var="imageName"  columns="3" emptyMessage="Aucune photo trouvée.">
                <p:panel id="pnl" header="#{imageName}" style="text-align:center">
                    <h:panelGrid columns="1" style="width:20%">

                        <p:graphicImage   url="/images/#{imageName}" style="width: 120px;height: 110px;"/>                  
                    </h:panelGrid>
                </p:panel>
                <p:draggable for="pnl" proxy="true" revert="true"  helper="clone" handle=".ui-panel-content" stack=".ui-panel"/>
            </p:dataGrid>
        </p:scrollPanel>
    </p:fieldset>
</h:form>
```

But the issue of slowness persist. I can't do nothing without correcting this problem.
I'm using JSF 2.1 with PrimeFaces 3.5

Any advice or idea are welcomed.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: How many Mb is 10Mo? Is that the total size? Have you excluded the client side from being the probable cause of the problem by trying it in as many different browsers as possible? For example Internet Explorer is known to be terribly inefficient.

Comment: 10Mo = 10 M Bytes  and this is the size of 1 picture. I trying chrome and Mozilla Firefox  browsers. But, it  give the same result(Slowness management).

Comment: So, your webapp shows 30 pictures of 10Mb each at once and thus consumes a minimum of 300Mb in client side?

Comment: Yes, i'm generating and saving  all these images with that  algorithm.

Comment: A JPEG file of 10MB corresponds an image of about 10,000 x 10,000 pixels in average quality. And then thirty of that supposedly tiled next each other. Do your clients really have that large screens? Sorry, but I'm surprised that you're surprised about the slowness when dealing with such images in client side and that you even suspected JSF being the probable cause.

Comment: I don't know if they have or not but in my case i have these pictures with their high qualities for application's input  . Then , i have to deal with.

Comment: No, you should scale them down to thumbnails when uploading and show those in tiles. Only when clicking an image, show a larger one (not even the full size one but an intermediate size (max 1600x900 e.g.) and only allow the full size as a download. That is how all serious image sites do it